# Remove horizontal whitespaces from HTML tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, tree, whitespace

I just need to automatically remove the unnecessary horizontal whitespace between nodes like  the three last grand children from this tree:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 -2px 0 -2px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;

  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>

<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The objective is to turn the tree narrower as possible without letting the 'a' elements overlap, also centralize li elements relative with only direct children

I have a larger tree generated by a R function that follows this model, so the nodes and edges may change

There is some css or js that solve this problem?

Comment: what whitespaces?

Comment: In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please do not just point us to code linked to another website. Code on that site might change or disappear over time, leaving the question here without any context for future readers. Your question becomes much easier to answer when the code you want help with is actually in the question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76926038/edit) and click the button in the toolbar that looks like `[<>]` to add a code snippet to your question

Comment: @vanowm between the three last grand children

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace between the list items is from the whitespace that you have between the `</li>` and `<li>` tags, which is being rendered because of `display: inline-block`.

The easiest fix is to use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) instead.

```
.tree ul {
  display: flex;
}

.tree li {
  /* display: inline-block; */
}
```

I thought to do a search before posting this answer to see if there is another fix. I believe that the solution I suggested is still the best for your situation, but you're welcome to use the search function and review the numerous previous answers over the past 15 years. I used the phrase "whitespace between list items".

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 -2px 0 -2px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;

  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>

<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

To remove ***all*** space between the list items, you'll need to remove your `margin` and `padding` declarations.

```
.tree li {
  /* margin: 0 -2px 0 -2px; */
  /* padding: 20px 5px 0 5px; */
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* margin: 0 -2px 0 -2px; */
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  /* padding: 20px 5px 0 5px; */
  padding-top: 20px;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;

  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>

<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, `display: flex` is the best option. In the old days, the only real way to remove the `inline-block` space was to butt the end and start tags together like so: `</li><li>`.

Comment: The result looks exactly the same though, the `Grand Child` elements are spread apart.

Comment: @vanowm It is unclear if the question is about the actual whitespace or the gap from the padding. I have edited my answer to include a second example removing the padding.

Comment: Their comment from deleted answer: "I need to remove the unnecessary gap between nodes like the three last grand children only not globally, turning the tree more narrow" so it's not the padding they are after...